# cypress cucumber preprocessor tags not working inside docker container

Tags: cucumber, cypress, preprocessor, ui-testing, end-to-end

When using the cypress cucumber preprocessor i have the following in my package.json

```
"ci-test": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS=\"@SOMETAG and not @OTHERTAG\""
```

When i run npm run ci-test it works and all scenarios with @OTHERTAG get ignored.

But when running the same command like so

```
npm run ci-$project -- --env username=$user,password=$password,loginrealm=$namespace
```

inside of a docker container, it just executes all tests tagged with @SOMETAG and ignores the second part of the command with "and not @OTHERTAG"

What also confuses me is the fact that the official documentation states i should use the command like

```
"ci-test": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@SOMETAG and not @OTHERTAG'"
```

but then it does not find any tag.

Answer (score 0):

The following Syntax did now work for me:

```
"ci-test": "npx cypress-tags run --env "TAGS=@SOMETAG and not @OTHERTAG,username=$username,password=$password"
```

Comment: Probably you want to mark your answer as a solution. Or you're still looking for better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Update your DockerFile Node Version

FROM:Node10 -> FROM:Node14

[image]